# Robocopy not copying files

Tags: command-line, robocopy

I am running robocopy via the command line using:

```
\\server1\devl\cfapps\cfeis\ctr" "\\server2\test\cfapps\cfeis\ctr" "edit_items.cfm " /purge /log:\\server1\cfapps\cfeis\mysync2\logs\rc_10092014_txt /NDL /r:2 /w:2
```

Sometimes this works, but other times it doesnt. The log file will say:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Started : Thu Oct 09 08:59:34 2014

Source : \\server1\devl\cfapps\cfeis\ctr\
Dest : \\server2\test\cfapps\cfeis\ctr\

Files : edit_items.cfm 

Options : /NDL /COPY:DAT /PURGE /R:2 /W:2 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
Files :        0         0         0         0         0         0
Bytes :        0         0         0         0         0         0
Times :  0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

Ended : Thu Oct 09 08:59:34 2014
```

This folder has way more than 1 directory and has a bunch of files, so apparently it'snot reading something correctly. I know the paths are correct and the user has the correct permissions, as it works every once in a while. What would stop this from working only sometimes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that there was a space after the file name. Removed that and it worked fine.